# Cannot call member function 'virtual void ' without object

Tags: virtual

Is there some way how to call function pure() from function of nested class?

G++ give me error: cannot call member function ‘virtual void Outer::pure()’ without object.

I do not know what to do.

```
  class Outer 
    {
    public:  
        class Nested
        {
        public:
            void function();
        };

    public:
        void print();
        virtual void pure() = 0;
    };

    void Outer::print() {
            printf("Hello! This is a test prgoram.\n");
        }

    void Outer::Nested::function()
    {
        Outer::pure();         // !!!!!! cannot call member function ‘virtual void Outer::pure()’ without object
        printf("Function\n");
    }

class D : Outer {
public:    
    void pure() override {
        printf ("pure\n");
    }

    void d_function() {
        printf ("d_function\n");
        print();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To call your virtual member function 'pure', you need an instance of 'D'. There is an implicit hidden parameter (this). You cannot call a function without passing it its required parameters.

You can add a parameter to Nested::function:

```
class Nested
{
public:
    void function(Outer& outer)
    {
        outer.pure();
    }
};
```

Or you can store a reference:

```
class Nested
{
public:
    Nested(Outer& outer) : outer{outer} {}
    void function()
    {
        outer.pure();
    }
private:
    Outer& outer;
};
```

For the second version you can provide a factory function:

```
class Outer
{
public:

    class Nested
    {
    public:
        Nested(Outer& outer) : outer{outer} {}
        void function()
        {
            outer.pure();
        }
    private:
        Outer& outer;
    };

    virtual void pure() = 0;

    auto make_nested()
    {
        return Nested{*this};
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
class Derived : public Outer
{
public:
    void pure() override
    {
        printf ("pure\n");
    };
};

int main()
{
    Derived derived;
    auto nested = derived.make_nested();
    nested.function(); // calls pure

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My first Version was slightly wrong. I corrected it now. Outer is an abstract class and cannot be instanziated. Now there's a derived class which implements 'pure'.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this Usage is impossible :-/.

I cant call:

```
Outer outer;
```

Class Outer has virtual void Outer::pure().

My errors:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:130:11: error: use of deleted function ‘Outer::Outer()’
     Outer outer;
           ^~~~~
main.cpp:81:7: note: ‘Outer::Outer()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class Outer
       ^~~~~
main.cpp:81:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘Outer::Nested::Nested()’
main.cpp:87:13: note: candidate: Outer::Nested::Nested(Outer&)
             Nested(Outer& outer) : outer{outer} {}
             ^~~~~~
main.cpp:87:13: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main.cpp:84:15: note: candidate: constexpr Outer::Nested::Nested(const Outer::Nested&)
         class Nested
               ^~~~~~
main.cpp:84:15: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main.cpp:84:15: note: candidate: constexpr Outer::Nested::Nested(Outer::Nested&&)
main.cpp:84:15: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main.cpp:130:11: error: cannot declare variable ‘outer’ to be of abstract type ‘Outer’
     Outer outer;
           ^~~~~
main.cpp:81:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Outer’:
 class Outer
       ^~~~~
main.cpp:99:22: note:   virtual void Outer::pure()
         virtual void pure() = 0;
```

Comment: You answered your own question, but this is not an answer but a response to my answer. I assume that you are not able to write comments yet. I had the same problem when I was a newbie. Please delete it when my answer is ok.